# OpenCV SURF crash after calling create()

Tags: opencv, runtime-error, surf

Couldnt google it...
OpenCV version 4.5.1
when calling

```
   Ptr<cv::xfeatures2d::SURF> detector = cv::xfeatures2d::SURF::create();
```

app crash. Others detectors ORB, FAST, SIFT are working properly. Where can be the issue? I found some old topic about this solved by calling initModule_nonfree(), but it is not included in version 4.5,1?

[image]

Comment: How did you install opencv? Have you built it from sources? Are you using Linux or Windows?

Comment: Hello,
from source, with contrib, on windows, without CUDA. What I only edited in cmake was EXTRA path, thats all what I remember, then building with visual studio 2019. I can use all libraries, all stuff, even RUN it, but when it comes to call CREATE on surf, it crash.

Comment: can you paste here the stack trace if you have it?

Comment: @Doch88 I have added that to the starting post

Comment: Seems like an exception, try putting that line in a try-catch like try {
           ...(your line)...
        } catch(cv::Exception  &ex) {
            std::cout <<  ex.msg.c_str() << std::endl;
        } 
And write in the post the output.

Comment: OMG.. I am realy bad when I forgot to use try catch syntax... Thanks a lot! Working on fix now 

OpenCV(4.5.1-dev) C:\src\openCVcontrib\modules\xfeatures2d\src\surf.cpp:1029: error: (-213:The function/feature is not implemented) This algorithm is patented and is excluded in this configuration; Set OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE CMake option and rebuild the library in function 'cv::xfeatures2d::SURF::create'

Of course I didnt check OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE ...

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved by rebulding with:

OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE = checked